# How to transfer KeyPointVector to Mat in javaCV

Tags: opencv, javacv, surf, opticalflow

I want to make an calcOpticalFlowPyrLK from feature points get from image, when I use goodFeaturesToTrack, everything is OK as following:

```
goodFeaturesToTrack(blackOutImagePrev, prevCorners, 200, 0.04, 30);
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(blackOutImagePrev, blackOutImageNext, prevCorners, nextCorners, status, err);
```

Due to the processing speed issue, I want to change the function that I get feature points to surf or fast method. For the surf, the function is:

```
final KeyPointVector kp = new KeyPointVector();
final SURF surf = SURF.create(2500, 4, 2, true, false);
surf.detect(image, kp);
```

Since the surf get feature points are stored in KeyPointVector, but the type of prevCorners is Mat. How could I transfer it to Mat so I can call the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK? Or there is any workaround?

Comment: Looks like a [`KeyPointVector`](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.KeyPointVector.html) is just a vector of [`KeyPoints`](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.KeyPoint.html). The `KeyPoints` type has the [`pt()` method](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.KeyPoint.html#pt--) which will return a `Point2f` which you can construct a `Mat` with. So create the new `Mat`, and loop through the keypoints vector, get the points with `pt()` and insert.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, it works.

Comment: Great! I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [KeyPointVector](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.KeyPointVector.html) is just a vector of [KeyPoints](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.KeyPoint.html). The KeyPoints type has the [pt() method](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.KeyPoint.html#pt--) which will return a `Point2f` which you can construct a `Mat` with. So create the new `Mat`, and loop through the keypoints vector, get the points with `pt()` and insert.